# Problems creating apk : 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I was trying create an apk for my project from Android Studio 0.8.9
It gives the following message:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageDebug FAILED
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageDebug'.
> File 'mykey' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

'mykey' is my storepath which i just created..what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. i assume you are using Android studio

Go to `Build` -> `Generate Signed APK`. `Create your key (or choose existing)` then `next` then `next` and finally `done`..!

Comment: Solved mine. I assume when you update Android Studio you must redo all actions... I already had a keystore and generated signed APK before, but after an update I had to search for my keystore again...

Answer (score 1):

For me, even though i followed : Build -> Generate Signed APK it still gave me the same error. What worked was to right click the app and go to "Open Module Settings" then click the "Signing" tab , then fill out and point the store file to what i had previously made in "Generate Signed APK"

Answer (score 0):

step 1 - Right Click on `Project explorer` then `open module settings` or click `f4` button

step 2-  click on  your project name

step 3-  Then click on   `signing` tab
         then click on `debug` then enter your `keystore` details
          and browse the store file to your `keystore` file that put in your `asset` folder.

- put `keystore` file in `asset` folder

and change the file name to 
`asset/signingConfig.storeFile`

Comment: for safety, the `keystore` file shouldn't be in the project repo